# Related resources in single response in FHIR

Tags: hl7-fhir

We have a use case where we need resources related to a single resource. In the front end part of our application, we have a requirement where we have a dashboard which showcases list of patient information

This list of Patient information includes display of CarePlan info too. We thought of using Bundle however, the bundle can simply list resources with resourceType field.

Question is how to logically put patient and related careplan as related resources in single object. We also have had a look at the compartment search, but fhir site does not show any examples how the sample response will be.

If anyone can tell us a way to group related resources with data(not just references) using fhir models it would be of a great help

Answer (score 2):

The only way to bring back multiple resource instances is with Bundle - other grouping mechanisms like List will only do references.  If you want to query for a patient and bring back their care plans too, you can use _revinclude to retrieve all care plans tied to that patient.

Comment: Adding to Lloyds answer: with a request like that, you will get back a Bundle containing several different resource types, which is perfectly okay in FHIR.
Example call: `GET <server>/Patient?_id=123&_revinclude=CarePlan:patient`

Comment: Yeah I can use Bundle, however we want to display rows of patient information
For Eg Each row in dashboard contains info in following format

    patient name| procedure name| careplan start date | end date and so on
1) . ABC | DEF| yyyy-mm-dd| yyyy-mm-dd
2) . GHI  | JKL | yyyy-mm-dd| yyyy-mm-dd

With Bundle I cannot get these type of combined results, all I can get is just flat list of resources. Client should handle mapping of patient info and respective careplan info in the flat list to display row wise. So is there a way to group info as stated above

Comment: FHIR in general isn't going to let you do that - the expectation is that you're passing around full resources.  Your only option to get the behavior you're looking for is to define a custom operation and pass back a Parameters instance that contains the specific data you're looking for.  It'll be much heavier than the syntax you've defined though.  I suppose you could have a custom operation that just passes back a string that could be formatted as you've defined, but at that point, you've really ceased to use FHIR at all...